# Sliding a BS3 Navbar out of the left

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was creating a Navbar for my BS Website and I just realized that sliding it out the left would appear appealing. So, to run it over,

1. The user clicks on `.navbar-toggle`.
2. Then the Navbar slides out of the left, 
   covering 3/4th the entire page. Something like
   what's on the **Airbnb** website:

[image: The Navbar on the Airbnb Website]

How do I do this? I'll wager you that this has something to do with the `slideIn()` jQuery function, so I'll add that tag too. Note that this navbar only happens when the user is on mobile.
Here's my code:

http://codepen.io/aravind-forever/pen/ozGkWZ

Comment: You need some css rules for your site, there is no need any extra jQuery. If you paste some code in jsfiddle, codepen (...) may be I can help you.

Comment: @Narek-T Roger that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey according to your Condition  you Want 3/4 sidebar that means if the whole page width is  `100%` you wantyour Sidebar to `75%`of that page then try the below fiddle demo hope it helps you 
[sidebar Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/DTcHh/25776/)

Comment: I'd like to say that your code is much less compared to the other answers, but it works well... thanks. again.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the thing that you want to do, you have to add some css rules and a little bit of jquery in the code.

Below is the link of the codepen that I've created. May be that can help :)

http://codepen.io/shashanksmaty/pen/pEWPaP

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandName</a>
</div>
<div class="container-nav">
  <div class="nav-mask"></div>
  <div class="nav-list">
    <div class="nav-list-wrap">
      <ul class="list-unstyle">
        <li><strong>Home</strong></li>
        <li><strong>Downloads</strong></li>
        <li><strong>Contacts</strong></li>
        <li><strong>About Us</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-nav{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-mask{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2001;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  right: -285px;
}

.nav-list-wrap {
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

.list-unstyle {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-unstyle li {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-unstyle li:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.container-nav').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('.nav-mask').css({
    "opacity": "0.6",
    "-webkit-transition": "opacity 0.5s ease-in",
    "transition": "opacity 0.5s ease-in"
  });
  $('.nav-list').css({
    "right": "0px",
    "-webkit-transition": "right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.61,.98)",
    "transition": "right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.61,.98)"
  });
});

$('.nav-mask').on('click', function(){
  $('.container-nav').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $('.nav-mask').css({
    "opacity": "0",
    "-webkit-transition": "opacity 0.5s ease-in",
    "transition": "opacity 0.5s ease-in"
  });
  $('.nav-list').css({
    "right": "-285px",
    "-webkit-transition": "right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.61,.98)",
    "transition": "right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.61,.98)"
  });
});
```